# how to call a service (or parameter of one service) from another service in wso2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2, restful-url, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 ESB for creating a rest API in json format. I have a restful json webservice which gives the response. I need to use one of the parameter of this response in another service call. 
How can i do this kind of service chaining in wso2 ESB.

for ex:-

i have a restful url as abc.com/cusotmer. I got the response back. Suppose "id" is one of the parameter of response.
I want to use this parameter in another service call (say, xyz.com/sheet) which internally calls the first service (abc.com/cusotmer).

Could any of you please help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

Service chaining is an important feature in any of the ESBs avaiable.

You can use [Call Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Call+Mediator) which keeps the control in the sequence (say your insequence)

You can use call for first endpoint , for second endpoint i am assuming the id is available in response body, you can either use json-eval or xpath to get this value, depending on type of data second service uses you can use [PayloadFactoryMediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator) and set id in desired body part

And in next line you can call again using Call Mediator or [Send](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Send+Mediator)

A rough code will be like.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                 { "A": "6", "tests": [{ "id": "xyz", "status": "new", "emp": [{ "Id": "12345" }] }], "student": [{ "Id": "65", "Name": "Ram" }] }
            </format>

        </payloadFactory>
<call>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="get" uri-template="http://192.168.1.10:8088/mockaxis2service"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
<!-- suppose id field comes as response in field name id2 -->
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
               {
                 "inp2second":"$1"       
               }
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="$.emp.id2"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
<call> or <send>
```

You can use either call or send mediator now ,send mediator to move the control to outsequence.

for json expression used above as `$.emp.id2` kindly refer [json support page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support) for example
An example of service chaining is also available [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/)

Comment: @ Rahul    

The response body of the 2nd service (from where i am picking the 'id' parameter) and the request body of the first service is in json format.  

where id of 'emp' field is retrieved from the 2nd service. could you let me know how to do it.

Comment: Sample request of first service :

     {
 "A": "6",
 "tests": [{
  "id": "xyz",
  "status": "new",
  "emp": [{
   "Id": "12345",
   
  }]
 }],
 "student": [{
  "Id": "65",
  "Name": "Ram"
 }]
}

Comment: updated the answer @user2326831 i would strongly suggest you to read the documentation on payloadfactory and json support links given above and think how to move with the solution i provided i dunno  the exact structure so i have assumed the body for second service, for multiple args you can add arg as $2,$3 etc

Comment: Thanks. I got the concept. one small ques which i am not able to figure it out. Suppose i have a response  which looks like this
 { 
"param1" : false, 
"param2" : 
{ 
"id" : "12345" , 
 "value" : "50" 
}, 


can you tell me if i want to retrieve the "value" field, how can i do it in wso2 esb ? 
and the above sample response is coming from a url, say "abc.com". Could you help me in this regard ?

Comment: You can use `$.param2.value` in either expression of property or in case you wanna use it in payloadfactory you can do as shown in my answer above. If wso2 is internally converting to xml by any chance the json , you can check by using `<log level="full"/>` then you can use xpath expression as well

Answer (score 0):

This is service chaining. You can refer to WSO2 library article which explains this clearly trough a example
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/

Comment: Most of the examples shown is of soap based. I could not find anything related to JSON object. Do you have any pointers

Comment: one small ques which i am not able to figure it out. Suppose i have a response  which looks like this
 { 
"param1" : false, 
"param2" : 
{ 
"id" : "12345" , 
 "value" : "50" 
}, 


  can you tell me if i want to retrieve the "value" field, how can i do it in wso2 esb ? 
and this response is coming from a url, say "abc.com". Could you help me in this regard